# Frame turns white when I use paint() method

Tags: java, swing, paint

In swing when I include a `paint()` method it just shows a white screen on the background.
First picture is the output with `paint()` and the second one is without `paint()`.

[image: With paint method]

[image: without paint method]

code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Board2 extends JFrame
{
    static JPanel p1
    static JButton b1
    public Board2(){
        setSize(1000, 800);
        setResizable(false);
        b1 = new JButton("Button");
        p1.add(b1);
        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(50,50,20,20);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Board2();

    }
}
```

In my other program the buttons were invisible until I mouse over them.  How can this be solved?

Comment: So, what's in your paint method?  Show us, so we can tell you what you've done wrong.

Comment: maybe this can be useful: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Comment: @DavidWallace Sorry I pasted the wrong code.

Comment: OK, MadProgrammer has given the correct answer.  You need `super.paint(g);` at the start of the `paint` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely cause of the problem is probably down to the fact that you've failed to call `super.paint`, but since you've not provided the paint code, it's only an educated guess...

Some other educated guesses...

- You're overriding `paint` (possibly of a top level container like `JFrame`), when you should be overriding `paintComponent` of something like `JComponent` or `JPanel` (and calling `super.paintComponent`)

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

**Updated based on updated code**

You have two basic problems...

```
public class Board2 extends JFrame
{

    //...

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(50,50,20,20);
    }
```

You're overriding `paint` of top level container and you're breaking the paint chain.

Painting in Swing is done by a series of chained method calls which work together to produce the final result, reach doing a particular job, when you fail to call `super.paint`, you stop these methods from working.

When you do this on a top level container you can prevent it from painting it's children as well...

Also, top level containers aren't double buffered, which makes them flicker when painted.

Instead, create yourself a custom component, override it's `paintComponent` and do your custom painting there

For example...

```
public class Board2 extends JFrame
{
    static JPanel p1
    static JButton b1
    public Board2(){
        setSize(1000, 800);
        setResizable(false);
        b1 = new JButton("Button");
        p1 = new JPanel() {
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillRect(50,50,20,20);
            }
        }
        p1.add(b1);
        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Board2();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be my best guess too; hopefully, OP will show us his/her source code soon.

Comment: What if I want to call the paintComponent method from another method or class?

Comment: You should never call paintComponent directly, instead, call repaint